# SharePoint calculated column if contains text

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint list (Issue Tracker), here I created a calculated column like `Product Name` and the formula is:

```
=IF((FIND("Laptop",Title)),"Laptop")
```

And, My requirement is when the user wants to add an issue based on the title then, the issue will appear under the Product name. But, whenever I have added one condition it will work but adding another condition then it will give an error.

[image]

Suggest any solution.

Comment: So according your requestion will always first word of the Title be product name? e.g. Product1 issue, Product2 issue ? and you want to store first word in the Product Name column>

Comment: @GaneshM, does my below answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this formula for your calculated column:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Laptop",Title)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Mobile",Title)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Outlook",Title)),"","Outlook"),"Mobile"),"Laptop")
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Thank you so much, sir

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped you. Keep using this platform to ask any questions related to SharePoint.

Comment: Hi @GaneshM, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.